# How to overlay a div in CSS

Tags: css

[image]

I'd like to know how [this website](https://www.bluechilli.com/investors) was able to do this in CSS

I tried to find how via inspect element but had no luck.
Is anyone able to reproduce this without using `position: relative`?

I was using:

```
{
   position: relative;
   top: -100px;
}
```

Comment: use a negative margin-top for the layer below and adjust properly its box-shadow

Comment: What you tried? show you code?

Comment: give a negative margin to your div so that it will be on purple background div.

Comment: That was a lot easier than expected, why don't you post as answer? @fcalderan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is to use a negative `margin-top` on the lower div.

```css
.upper{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-color:green;
}
.lower{
  width:80%;
  height:100px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0;
  background-color:red;
  margin-top:-30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="upper"></div>
<div class="lower"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, much easier than expected.

Comment: I have to wait 10 minutes.